# How to download multiple files from a single hyperlink

Tags: java, android, http

I am working on a task where I need to download multiple files from a single hyperlink. When I call the one API link I want it to return multiple files.

My current code is only downloading a single file:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
    URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
    conection.connect();
    // getting file length
    int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

    // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

    // Output stream to write file
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

    byte data[] = new byte[1024];

    long total = 0;

    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        // publishing the progress....
        // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
        publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

        // writing data to file
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }

    // flushing output
    output.flush();

    // closing streams
    output.close();
    input.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with any HTTP protocol which allows you to send multiple files in one response, unless they're zipped. I'm curious, what does the server response look like?

Comment: @323go This would return a multiple list of stream object/file

Comment: What standard does it follow?

Comment: @323go I did not get you about what you meant of standard ?

Comment: HTTP is a standard communication protocol. You send a request, you get a response. The request and response are well-defined. What standard does this request -> multiple-response scenario follow? Where is it defined? My knowledge of HTTP isn't exhaustive, but I've never seen this scenario. If it's a proprietary extension to the HTTP protocol, you likely won't get help with implementing a client unless you can define the server.

Answer (score 0):

check this [site](http://javadigest.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/downloading-multiple-files-using-multipart-response/) . It downloads multiple files and shows its content on your screen